# Problems regarding usage of Bodyguard library in Phoenix

Tags: authentication, authorization, elixir, phoenix-framework

We are trying to create a sample project using the Bodyguard library in Phoenix. We are just going to set some rules for users, as shown on the GitHub page, https://github.com/schrockwell/bodyguard. However, we are facing errors regarding the `conn` variable in `lib\bg_web\controllers\post_controller.ex`. We have uploaded our project in https://github.com/yashdani/bg. Please help us to identify the errors. Also, tell us what else we need to code in the project. We are really stuck, and we could not find any more information from the online documentation.

This is one of the errors:-

```
C:\Users\yashd\bg>mix phx.server
Compiling 18 files (.ex)
warning: variable "conn" does not exist and is being expanded to "conn()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  lib/bg_web/controllers/post_controller.ex:6


== Compilation error in file lib/bg_web/controllers/post_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/bg_web/controllers/post_controller.ex:6: undefined function conn/0
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:198: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

Comment: "we are facing errors" what's the exact error?

Comment: We have edited our question.

Comment: Include the problematic code here; don't make us go anywhere. It tells you precisely where the error is--wouldn't it make sense to include at *least* that code?!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the keyword `do`, instead of:

```
  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "post" => post_params})
```

should be:

```
  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "post" => post_params}) do
```